# Ajax and custom viewstate provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have implemented a custom viewstate provider from this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8001/ViewState-Provider-an-implementation-using-Provide

This is working fine with full postback but with partial postback (Ajax) it's not working, Can some one please provide solution for this, Or guide me where this thing is going wrong I have no clue.

Comment: When you say not working what do you mean ? The cases here is the page to keep the same viewstate id (vsKey) on partial post back and the viewstate is ether stay the same ether not updated inside the database on server - other than that I do not see other issues with partial post back.

Comment: @Aristos Controls like pager etc. are not maintaining their state in partial postnacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved this mess, Thanx to **Aristos** for giving me clue about the problem.

Here's what I have done just change this method in **SqlViewStateProvider.cs**

```
public override void SavePageState(System.Web.UI.Control pControl, object viewState)
{
  string vsKey = String.Empty;

  //    Searching for the hidden field named "__vsKey"

  // Comment out this line 
  //System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden ctrl = System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden)pControl.FindControl("__vsKey");

 // Add this line
  string lastKey = ((Page)pControl).Request.Form["__vsKey"];
  if (lastKey == null)
  {
     // Generate new GUID
     vsKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     // Store in the hidden field

     // Remove this line its old school code
     //((Page)pControl).RegisterHiddenField("__vsKey", vsKey);
     // Add this new one
     ((Page)pControl).ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__vsKey", vsKey);
   }
   else
   {
     // Use the GUID stored in the hidden field

     // Comment this one out
     //vsKey = ctrl.Value;

     // Add these two lines
     vsKey = lastKey;
     ((Page)pControl).ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("__vsKey", lastKey);
   }

// Every thing else is just as-is...

}
```

Hope this could help some one else too struggling with same problem.